# Python Regex: Matching potentially multiple characters within the parentheses

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I would love to get some help on getting the regex pattern to match multiple characters within a string.

Potential Inputs

- `The paragraph E(1)`
- `The paragraph E(1)(a)`
- `The paragraph E(1)(a)(ii)`
- `The paragraph E(1)(a)(ii) and paragraph G(1)(b)`

Outputs

- `E(1)`
- `E(1)(a)`
- `E(1)(a)(ii)`
- `E(1)(a)(ii)`, `G(1)(b)`

So far, I have the following regex that gets

```
import re


# Wrong. Should be ["E(1)"]
re.findall("[A-Z]\(\d{1,3}\)\([a-z]\)","The paragraph E(1)")
>>> []

# Correct
re.findall("[A-Z]\(\d{1,3}\)\([a-z]\)","The paragraph E(1)(a)")
>>> ["E(1)(a)"]

# Wrong. Should be ["E(1)(a)(ii)"]
re.findall("[A-Z]\(\d{1,3}\)\([a-z]\)","The paragraph E(1)(a)(ii)")
>>> ["E(1)(a)"]

# Wrong. Should be ["E(1)(a)(ii)", "G(1)(b)"]
re.findall("[A-Z]\(\d{1,3}\)\([a-z]\)","The paragraph E(1)(a)(ii) and paragraph G(1)(b)")
>>> ["E(1)(a)", "G(1)(b)"]
```

Comment: You may use: `\b[A-Z]\(\d{1,3}\)(?:\([a-z]+\))*`

Comment: AMAZING! it worked. i had to remove the ```\b``` to get it working, but this is what worked for me

```"[A-Z]\(\d{1,3}\)(?:\([a-z]+\))*"```

Comment: Of course `\b` would not work because you are using a regular string literal. Always use **raw** string literals to define regex patterns, `r"\b[A-Z]\(\d{1,3}\)(?:\([a-z]+\))*"`

Answer (score 1):

anubhava provided the answer

```
re.findall("[A-Z]\(\d{1,3}\)(?:\([a-z]+\))*","The paragraph E(1)")
>>> ["E(1)"]

re.findall("[A-Z]\(\d{1,3}\)(?:\([a-z]+\))*","The paragraph E(1)(a)")
>>> ["E(1)(a)"]

re.findall("[A-Z]\(\d{1,3}\)(?:\([a-z]+\))*","The paragraph E(1)(a)(ii)")
>>> ["E(1)(a)(ii)"]

re.findall("[A-Z]\(\d{1,3}\)(?:\([a-z]+\))*","The paragraph E(1)(a)(ii) and paragraph G(1)(b)")
>>> ["E(1)(a)(ii)", "G(1)(b)"]
```